# Paper for software tool - Medical Domain

Tags: publications, writing, computer-science

This is really related to this question ([Creating paper on software tool](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14173/creating-paper-on-software-tool)).

But there was [this comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14173/creating-paper-on-software-tool#comment26332_14173) there which asked for more details about the software's domain.

I created (still in beta stage) a software for Brain Tumor, but I would like to publish (if possible) about the software itself and not so much on the validation of it. (This would be eventually a later paper).

What's is the best approach for publishing about this software *"proposal"* for usage in medical clinics?

<sub>My concern is that while it's being tested. It wasn't tested enough for a full paper, but I still want to publish it.</sub>

Comment: I think it is pretty unlikely anyone would use a software so critical without good testing. You can publish it informally and get some user feedback, but I doubt you would get a paper.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to publish software in a quality scientific journal it is usually required that it represents a significant advance over previously published software, which is usually demonstrated by direct comparison with available related software. There will be no way to get around this.

I would also recommend to put the code on github (http://github.com). Github is more and more recognized as THE resource for code hosting. It is a free service for public repositories, and it is widely accepted in the community, e.g. you can register your Github repos with Impactstory (http://impactstory.org).

"Source Code for Biology and Medicine" (http://www.scfbm.org) might be an appropriate journal for you.

Comment: there is no current software that does something related to this. I know that this is quite rare specially regarding to software's and that's why I cannot really compare with something else. I would have to test on clinics, wait months and compare what the physicians used to do and compare with this automated usage.